# Dúvida com manipulação de TreeView e arquivos TXT delimitado

Tags: delphi, txt, treeview

estou com uma pequena dificuldade com Delphi, estou criando uma pequena aplicação bem básica pra eu gerenciar contas, de jogos, emails etc algo bem básico.. e eu resolvi usar o esquema do TreeView como base de listagem das contas, mas estou tendo uma grande dificuldade o que eu quero fazer basicamente é registrar arquivos num TXT, e fazer com que a aplicação leia o arquivo delimitado por ";" e ele crie itens e subitens dependendo do que eu quero visualizar, como se cada item fosse uma categoria, tipo Emails, Jogos, etc... Vou enviar uma Print de como eu queria tirar umas dúvidas se alguém puder me ajudar com isso e souber.. agradeço desde já 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual é a duvida ao certo?

Comment: Eu queria fazer a aplicação ler arquivos de texto delimitados por ;  e ler os dados como está na imagem, só que até  ai de ler ta OK funciona, o fato é botar isso numa Treeview, tipo cada  Nó principal ser usado  a primeira TAG de cada coluna por exemplo
"Email, Games, Steam" como Tags Pais ou seja os subitens seriam apenas  o resto das informações especificas de cada categoria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você apontou nos comentários, que a sua dificuldade é montar uma estrutura no *TreeView*, vou deixar uma solução com esse foco.

Para a solução usei:

- Um *TMemo* como base para o arquivo.
- Um *TTreeView*.
- Um *TValueListEditor* para armazenar os campos que ficarão fora da árvore, invisível pois vai servir apenas para guardar os dados temporários.
- Outro *TMemo* para mostrar os campos do nó selecionado na árvore.

[image: Print de quais componentes usar no form]

## Códigos

### Declarar o tipo `TVetorDeString`

```
type
   TVetorDeString = array of string;
```

### Clique do botão "Processar"

```
var
   i: Integer;
   Linha: TVetorDeString;
   NohNivel1: TTreeNode;
   NohNivel2: TTreeNode;
begin
   SetLength(Linha, 0);

   for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
   begin
      Linha := StringParaVetor(Memo1.Lines[i]);

      NohNivel1 := nil;
      NohNivel2 := nil;

      AddNoh(NohNivel1, nil, Linha[0]);
      AddNoh(NohNivel2, NohNivel1, Linha[1]);

      ValueListEditor1.Strings.Add(Format('%s;%s;1=%s', [Linha[0], Linha[1], Linha[2]]));
      ValueListEditor1.Strings.Add(Format('%s;%s;2=%s', [Linha[0], Linha[1], Linha[3]]));
      ValueListEditor1.Strings.Add(Format('%s;%s;3=%s', [Linha[0], Linha[1], Linha[4]]));
   end;
end;
```

### Clique do *TreeView1*

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if TreeView1.Selected.Parent = nil then
   begin
      Exit;
   end;

   Memo2.Clear;
   Memo2.Lines.Add(ValueListEditor1.Values[Format('%s;%s;1', [TreeView1.Selected.Parent.Text, TreeView1.Selected.Text])]);
   Memo2.Lines.Add(ValueListEditor1.Values[Format('%s;%s;2', [TreeView1.Selected.Parent.Text, TreeView1.Selected.Text])]);
   Memo2.Lines.Add(ValueListEditor1.Values[Format('%s;%s;3', [TreeView1.Selected.Parent.Text, TreeView1.Selected.Text])]);
end;
```

### Função `StringParaVetor`

```
function StringParaVetor(const pString: String; const pDelimitador: Char = ';'): TVetorDeString;
var
   i: Integer;
   aux: string;

  begin
     SetLength(Result, 0);
     aux := EmptyStr;

     for i := 1 to Length(pString) do
     begin
        if pString[i] = pDelimitador then
        begin
           SetLength(Result, Length(Result)+1);
           Result[High(Result)] := aux;
           aux := EmptyStr;
           Continue;
        end;

        aux := aux + pString[i]
     end;

     SetLength(Result, Length(Result)+1);
     Result[High(Result)] := aux;
end;
```

### Procedure `AddNoh`

```
   procedure AddNoh(var pNoh: TTreeNode; const pNohPai: TTreeNode; const pTexto: String);
   var
      i: Integer;
   begin
      if pNohPai = nil then
      begin
        for i := 0 to TreeView1.Items.Count-1 do
        begin
           if TreeView1.Items[i].Text = pTexto then
           begin
              pNoh := TreeView1.Items[i];
              Break;
           end;
        end;

        if pNoh = nil then
        begin
           pNoh := TreeView1.Items.Add(pNohPai, pTexto);
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
         pNoh := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(pNohPai, pTexto);
      end;
   end;
```

## Explicando

### Button1Click

Percorrer linha-a-linha do *StringList* do *Memo1*

`for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do`

Cada linha foi transformada em um vetor com a função *StringParaVetor*:

A posição 1 do vetor é um nó de primeiro nível, adiciono ele só se ainda não foi adicionado usando a procedure `AddNoh`:

`AddNoh(NohNivel1, nil, Linha[0]);`

A posição 2 do vetor é um nó de segundo nível (filho do primeiro nível):

`AddNoh(NohNivel2, NohNivel1, Linha[1]);`

Posições 3, 4 e 5 são os campos a serem salvos no ValueListEditor1, são salvos cada campo em uma linha com uma "chave" que identifica cada linha:

```
  ValueListEditor1.Strings.Add(Format('%s;%s;1=%s', [Linha[0], Linha[1], Linha[2]]));
  ValueListEditor1.Strings.Add(Format('%s;%s;2=%s', [Linha[0], Linha[1], Linha[3]]));
  ValueListEditor1.Strings.Add(Format('%s;%s;3=%s', [Linha[0], Linha[1], Linha[4]]));
```

Essa parte pode ser otimizada com um laço, para várias linhas.

### TreeView1Click

Para mostrar no *Memo2* ao clicar no nó correspondente, a ideia é buscar a "chave" guardada no ValueListEditor1, e adicionar o Value correspondente.

Comment: Realmente era isso que eu queria, eu agradeço pela ajuda, ajudou muito, eu sempre tive dúvidas de como utilizar o Treeview sofri perdi muito tempo, mas felizmente você sanou minhas dúvidas, acredito que muita gente também  tem dificuldade de utilizar este componente.

Comment: bacana, que bom que ajudei, sucesso!